# Merge two columns of matrix, keeping only highest values

Tags: r, merge, highest

Is there a simple way of merging two columns of a data frame, keeping only the highest overall value per row? Example:

```
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(12, rate=.1), ncol=2))

test

         V1        V2
1  9.945558  5.578294
2  5.141743  5.946177
3 20.078324  9.773958
4  4.222424  2.098666
5 21.787726  3.094479
6 32.177890 11.059363
```

Desired outcome:

```
[1]  9.945558  5.946177 20.078324  4.222424 21.787726 32.177890
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pmax` to perform this operation:

```
test <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(12, rate=.1), ncol=2))

test
          V1         V2  
1  2.9683040  9.8769267  
2 11.5428303  2.4024274  
3  0.6843035 10.5813406  
4  2.5058739  5.2442930  
5  7.4704735  0.2269433  
6 15.7055989 12.3503810  

pmax(test$V1, test$V2)
[1]  9.876927 11.542830 10.581341  5.244293  7.470473 15.705599
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(test, 1, max)
```

will do the job!